# Ubuntu upgrade to 18.04, could only get into the system through recovery mode. If not, will hang indefinitely

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, kernel

Ubuntu upgrade to 18.04, then could only get into the system through recovery mode. If not, will hang indefinitely.

Comment: Where does it hang? We need much more information to be able to help you. At the GRUB menu, hit "e" to go into edit more. Locate and change "quiet splash" to "", then control-x to continue booting. Note where the script on the screen errors or hangs.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to re-install some packages:
sudo apt --reinstall install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
and probably some more. Maybe you can have a look at the part of /var/log/syslog that contains information on failed boots to get some hints where the problem is.

Success!

Comment: This really doesn't provide an answer. It should really be a comment.